# Converting a fix msg to indivdual attributes

Tags: java, mapping, translation, fix-protocol

I have a fix msg coming in which I need to extract the invdividual attributes. Is there any Java jars or libs currently out there with added fix functionality. Currently looking over QuickFIX/J This however seems to be more focused on send and receiving the FIX msgs. Has anyone any experience in work with translating a FIX msg to it's various objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every message class has a set of functions to extract the fields in the message and standard. An example class [MassQuote](http://www.quickfixj.org/quickfixj/javadoc/1.5.0/quickfix/fix50/MassQuote.html).

There are named get methods which return you the field. Else you can use the generic getField to return you the field attribute. In case of groups, first get the number of groups and then iterate over the message and use the getGroup method, to extract all groups.

Answer (score 0):

[MessageUtils](http://www.quickfixj.org/quickfixj/javadoc/1.5.0/quickfix/MessageUtils.html) have `getStringField` and `parse` methods which look useful